# Como pegar vários arrays com 1 único índice e colocar em um único array?

Tags: php, array

Estou a 3 dias tentando resolver um problema, não consigo pegar vários arrays com 1 único indice e colocar e um único array.

```
EX:
Está imprimindo assim:
Array(
      [0]=> "MT"
     )
Array(
      [0]=> "MG"
     )
Array(
      [0]=> "AM"
     )

Quero fazer assim:

Array([0]=>"MT", [1]=>"MT", [2]=>"MT")


//MEU BANCO DE DADOS CONSIDERANDO APENAS AS PESSOAS DA REDE DO ID 1001

id_usuario |  uf
-------------------------
1001          |  SP
1003          | MG
1005          | AM
1027          | MT

// MONTAGEM DA REDE

                 1001
                /    \
             1003     1005
              /
           1027
```

Meu código:

```
<?php 
function buscarEstados1($id){
    include 'includes/conexao.php'; 

    $s_down = "select id from tab_afiliado where upline = $id";
    $res_down = $cnns->query($s_down);
    foreach ($res_down as $down){
        $aff_uf = $down['id'];//var_dump($aff_uf); //PEGA OS IDS 1003, 1027, 1005

        $s_uf = "select uf,id_endereco from tab_endereco WHERE id_endereco = " . $aff_uf . "";
        $res_uf = $cnns->query($s_uf);
        foreach ($res_uf as $uf){
            $arr = $uf['uf']; //var_dump($arr); //PEGA AS UF MG , AM , MT 
        }

        buscarEstados1($aff_uf);
    }
}

    buscarEstados1(1001);
?>
```

Gostaria de pegar as UF e fazer um array  só `Array ( "MG" , "AM" , "MT");`

O problema é como se o loop pegasse assim.

```
 print_r(#arr);

    $arr = array( "MG" );
    $arr = array( "MT" ); 
    $arr = array( "AM" );
```

Comment: tente corrigir isso no momento da montagem do array. Se não for viável terá que fazer um POG básico. (Programação Orientada a Gambiarra)

Comment: Esses valores vem da onde do banco? não ficou muito claro qual é o problema.

Comment: Pq a função se chama(final do primeiro foreach) e não retornada nada?

Comment: **include** não deve estar dentro de uma função recursiva, coloque ele no inicio do arquivo evitara muitas dores de cabeça.


Acredito que ficaria mais fácil corrigirem o problema se você postasse o código de **conexao.php**

Comment: Esse resultado acontece pq 1 - `$arr` tem seu valor sobrescrito a cada volta do foreach, 2 - a função não retorna valor e se chama novamente.

Comment: Você pode marcar a resposta que mais te ajudou a resolver o problema(Guilherme Lautert) como aceita, ela fica com um sinal verde, ou criar sua propria resposta e explicar os detalhes. Veja => http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91

Answer (score 1):

Crie duas funções para facilitar a lógica, uma para buscar todos os afiliados e outra para buscar o respectivo estado.

```
function buscarAfiliados($id){
    include 'includes/conexao.php'; 

    $s_down = "select id from tab_afiliado where upline = $id";
    $res_down = $cnns->query($s_down);
    foreach ($res_down as $down){
     $aff_uf = $down['id'];

     return $cnns->query($s_uf);
    } 
}

function buscarEstados($id){
    include 'includes/conexao.php'; 
    $s_uf = "select uf,id_endereco from tab_endereco WHERE id_endereco = " . $id . "";
    $res_uf = $cnns->query($s_uf);
    foreach ($res_uf as $uf){
        $arr[] = $uf['uf']; 
    }
    return $arr;
}

    $afiliados = buscarAfiliados(1001);

    foreach($afiliados as $item){
        $estados[] =buscarEstados($item['uf'])
    }
```

Comment: rray não funcionou pq o meu loop está pegando os arrays como se fossem o mesmo todos com indice [0] Assim: $arr = array( "MG" );
print_r($arr);
$arr = array( "MT" );
print_r($arr);
$arr = array( "AM" );
print_r($arr);

Comment: @clicabarato ainda não consegui entender ...

Comment: Como se o loop pegasse ele assim... $arr = array('MG'); $arr = array('MT'); $arr = array('AM');

Comment: Quando dou um print_r($arr) ele mostra assim MG MT AM... Cada um com o mesmo array e indice [0]

Comment: Esse é o objetivo! para pegar os valores pode usar um foreach ou `implode()` caso queira formatar como uma string.

Comment: @clicabarato acho que você precisa editar a pergunta e adicionar mais detalhes, se você ler a primeira frase da pergunta e [esse comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107351/como-pegar-v%C3%A1rios-arrays-com-1-%C3%BAnico-%C3%ADndice-e-colocar-em-um-%C3%BAnico-array#comment221124_107358) parece que foi resolvido.

Comment: @clicabarato um join não resolveria esse problema? no lugar de fazer dois foreach?

Comment: Não resolveria pq o grande problema é ter que pegar no BD linha por linha cado pessoa que esta abaixo de seus respectivos UpLines em cada um de suas proprias redes.... senão o que eu quero fazer seria muito simples usando o próprio  DISTINCT

Comment: primeiro preciso pegar o id principal da rede e depois pegar seus 2 Downllines e assim sucessivamente e não vejo outra forma

Comment: Obrigado rray, vou achei interessante essa organizações de funçoes pois estou iniciando agora em programação, espero um dia chegar a ser fera assim igual vcs !....=D

Answer (score 1):

Eu não faria assim, mas lhe dando uma alternativa seria :

```
<?php 
function buscarEstados1($id, &$arr = array()){
    include 'includes/conexao.php'; 

    $s_down = "select id from tab_afiliado where upline = $id";
    $res_down = $cnns->query($s_down);
    foreach ($res_down as $down){
        $aff_uf = $down['id'];//var_dump($aff_uf); //PEGA OS IDS 1003, 1027, 1005

        $s_uf = "select uf,id_endereco from tab_endereco WHERE id_endereco = " . $aff_uf . "";
        $res_uf = $cnns->query($s_uf);
        foreach ($res_uf as $uf){
            $arr[] = $uf['uf']; //var_dump($arr); //PEGA AS UF MG , AM , MT 
        }

        buscarEstados1($aff_uf, $arr);
    }
}

    $ufs = array();
    buscarEstados1(1001, $ufs);

    print_r($ufs); // Seu Resultado
?>
```

Comment: Guilherme Obrigado o seu tbm funcionou, só faltou retornar no recursivo da função buscarEstados1($aff_uf, $arr);

Comment: Vou usar o seu código pq ficou mais curto, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Faça um loop obtendo os valores do array multidimensional e jogando-os para um array simples.

No exemplo abaixo sobrescreve-se o próprio array original:

```
$arr = array(array('a'), array('b'), array('c'));

foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    $arr[$k] = $v[0];

print_r($arr);
```

Caso queira modificar a estutura da consulta SQL, usando JOIN, veja exemplo abaixo

```
    <?php 
    function buscarEstados1($id){
        include 'includes/conexao.php'; 


        $sql = "select 
        T1.id AS id,
        T3.id AS afiliado_id,
        T2.uf AS uf, 
        T2.id_endereco AS id_endereco
        from tab_afiliado AS T1
        LEFT JOIN tab_afiliado AS T3 ON T3.upline = T1.id
        LEFT JOIN tab_endereco AS T2 ON T2.id_endereco = T1.id"
        where upline = $id";

        $rs = $cnns->query($sql);

        print_r($rs); exit;

/**
O restante do código omiti pois não entendi porque está fazendo recursividade.
*/
    }
```

Comment: Daniel na verdade está como se estivesse assim: $arr = array('a'); $arr = array('b');  $arr = array('c');   ... Por isso não estou conseguindo já troquei a posição de todas as formas mas sempre mostra assim  =(

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta pois isso muda bastante a resposta. Não está claro como é o primeiro array

Comment: Daniel pega aquele codigo que editei agora e imprime ai para vc ver o que realmente o codigo está fazendo

Comment: não entendi onde modificou.  O problema é entender como é montado o primeiro array que contém `Array(
      [0]=> "MT"
     )`, entendeu? Esse primeiro array está assim? `array(array('a'), array('b'), array('c'));` ou assim `array(''a); array('b'); array('c')` É um array multidimensional ou são 3 arrays?

Comment: são 3 arrays, pois eu não estava conseguindo colocar ele em 1 array só

Comment: entendi. vc pode resolver de várias formas.. uma forma é fazer uma unica consulta SQL usando JOIN.. vc quer mesmo fazer essas gambiarras com array ou quer melhorar a query? Sugiro a query

Comment: Como eu faria esse JOIN? Considerando que preciso puxar apenas as pessoas de suas respectivas redes?

Comment: adicionei sugestão de join na resposta.. mas agora percebi que vc faz uma chamada recursiva `buscarEstados1()`. Por que precisa disso?

Comment: Faço a recurcividade para voltar o id do próximo da rede que vai entrar abaixo dele mais 2 ids e assim por diante sempre voltando o id do próximo da rede, pois ele busca primeiro o lado esquerdo e depois o lado direito com esta no desenho da rede que fiz ali na pergunta

Comment: Saquei! Isso precisa de algo mais sofisticado. Já fica completamente fora de contexto. Você tem duas opções que é mudar completamente a pergunta ou continuar na gambiarra com arrays.

Comment: opaaa...ideias é sempre muito bem vindas.... Qual a idéia?

Comment: estava vendo aqui o JOIN e ele pega apenas os 2 indicados do primeiro da rede, depois precisaria pegar os indicados desse 2 e assim por diante

Comment: fiz o join antes de vc falar desse esquema de piramide.. Isso parece sistema de pirâmide/rede, não?

Comment: Acho que precisará remodelar muita coisa se quiser fazer algo mais eficiente. Veja que no id_endereço está usando o mesmo id do afiliado. O ideal seria ter um campo só para referência do id do afiliado pois imagine quando precisar adicionar mais de um endereço por afiliado.  Aí já tem uma complicação e provavelmente vai resolver com gambiarra no banco de dados e isso vai virando uma bola de neve. Vc deixa para "arrumar depois" mas na verdade nunca arrruma rsrs. Por isso, sugiro refazer a modelagem. Melhor sofrer agora no começo quando está pequeno do que ver um pesadelo com isso já grande.

Comment: modifiquei a query. Rode aí e veja o resultado. Adicionei o relacionamento com a mesma tabela , retornando os ids da rede. Dessa forma não precisa fazer essa recursividade e reduzirá muito o código e processamento.